# Cannot print else statement in solution

Tags: c#

i solved an assignment question on my own but i seems not to be able to print an else statement successfully even though the code works.
The questions is below,

Create a program that prompts the user for the first number. Show on the screen which number was chosen and if the 
Number is greater than 10 then show your predecessors until you reach number 10.

My solution is below,

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter interger please: ");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();



        for (int num3 = num; 10 <= num3; num3-- )
        {
            if (num > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num3);
            }

            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("The integer entered is less than zero and cannot be used in code ");
            }
```

Comment: `"even though the code works"` - If the code "works" then what exactly is the problem here?  What are you asking?

Comment: Have you considered debugging it?

Comment: Just a guess, but do you need a Console.ReadLine() at the end to prevent the terminal from exiting?

Comment: @CNuts, wow...this took care of it perfectly.I did not know i could put a for loop inside an if statement.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's normal that in doesn't enter the else statement. You're doing `if (num > 10)` and `num` is the value entered by the user which never changes during the process. So if `num = 15` you're always doing is 15 > 10.

Then only moment the else statement is gonna print is if the number entered is 10.

And the moment `num` is smaller than 10, you'll never get in the for loop so the number will never be smaller than 0 **inside** the loop so that line won't make sense even if it's played

```
Console.WriteLine("The integer entered is less than zero and cannot be used in code ");
```

Cause like i said if this line is printed that means the value in `num` was 10 which is not less than zero.

You could change it for something like this

```
if(num < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's smaller than 10");
}

for(int num3 = num; 10 <= num3; num3--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num3);
}
```

Comment: @David,the code works but i want to be able to notify user that the number entered is lower than 10 and cannot be used

Comment: @liam,thanks,i would do that

Comment: ,thanks,you are right,i have evn tried using else if without any solution.I feel there should be a way around it to print the else statement

Comment: @Eniola.A Check my edit.

Comment: wow...this took care of it perfectly.I did not know i could put a for loop inside an if statement.Thanks a lot

Comment: @Eniola.A Happy I could help :)

Comment: @Eniola.A Consider [Accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem so you can close this question.

Comment: ,i am new to stack overflow and had no idea you can accept answers to close questions,google helped out and i have ticked and accepted your answer as best,thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

You're decrementing "num3" on the for loop, but you're validating if "num" is greater than 10 which, by entering the loop in the first place, will always be true.
    Change to:

```
if (num3 > 10)
{
   Console.WriteLine(num3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to provide the question?
The code you have written seems a little meaningless.
Firstly, the for loop will only run if you enter an integer >= 10

Rewriting your code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive integer: ");
    var args = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(args, out int num))
    {
        if (num < 0)
            Console.WriteLine('Must enter a positive integer!');

        for (var i = num; i >= 10; i-- )
        {
           //this only runs if the integer entered is >= 10 
           if (num > 10)
           {
             Console.WriteLine(i);
           }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A non-integer was entered!");
    }
```

Comment: ,thanks..am already aware that the for loop would not run if interger <= 10 is entered.I also provided the question above.Am just looking for a better way to rewrite the code and the code you wrote has bugs and cannot run successfully.